# How to print number ranges omitting common prefix?

Tags: python-3.x

I have a list that contains tuples of telephone number ranges. Each tuple has only two elements, a start and an end number. A sample list is as follows:

`telephone_ranges = [(5122251726, 5122251743), (5122252700, 5122252724), (5123687021, 5123687021), (5123687025, 5123687025), (7373463555, 7373463654)]`

How can I print each range in the format of `start number - end number`, while only printing the unique numbers in the `end number`. That is, I do not want to print the shared prefix. The `start number` should always be printed fully.Expected result is:

`5122251726 - 43
5122252700 - 24
5123687021
5123687025
7373463555 - 654`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [os.path.commonprefix](https://docs.python.org/3/library/os.path.html#os.path.commonprefix).

```
import os

telephone_ranges = [(5122251726, 5122251743), (5122252700, 5122252724), (5123687021, 5123687021), (5123687025, 5123687025), (7373463555, 7373463654)]
for (a, b) in telephone_ranges:
    if a==b:
        print(a)
        continue

    a, b = map(str, (a, b))
    if len(a)==len(b):
        prefix = os.path.commonprefix((a, b))
        b = b[len(prefix):]

    print(f"{a} - {b}")
```

Comment: Clever use of commonprefix.

Answer (score 0):

This piece of code should solve your problem:

```
telephone_numbers = [(5122251726, 5122251743), (5122252700, 5122252724), (5123687021, 5123687021), (5123687025, 5123687025), (7373463555, 7373463654)]
final = []
for number in telephone_numbers:
    # converting the numbers to string for easy comparisons
    a = str(number[0])
    b = str(number[1])

    # checking if both the telephone numbers are same
    if a == b:
        final.append(a)

    # looping through each character and checking if a match is available in the second number
    for i in range(len(a)):
        if a[:i] in b:
            continue
        else:
            # converting back to integers
            final.append((int(a), int(b[(i-1):])))
```

Answer (score 0):

The first python I have ever written! I may have thought about this from a Javascript & PHP background.

[PythonFiddle.com](http://pythonfiddle.com/)

```
import sys

telephone_ranges = [(5122251726, 5122251743), (5122252700, 5122252724), (5123687021, 5123687021), (5123687025, 5123687025), (7373463555, 7373463654)]

for telephone_range in telephone_ranges:
  firstTel = str(telephone_range[0])
  firstTelReversed = firstTel[::-1]

  secondTel = str(telephone_range[1])
  secondTelReversed = secondTel[::-1]

  sys.stdout.write(firstTel)

  for idx, digit in enumerate(secondTelReversed):
    if digit != firstTelReversed[idx]:
      if idx == 0:
          sys.stdout.write(' - ')
      sys.stdout.write(digit)

  print
```